# Can you spawn gameobjects and move them to an x position that is added by the last one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am very new to Unity game development and was just curious if there was any way to spawn a gameobject in a position then the next game object in that position added like for is 1 then the next one will be 2 then 3 and so on.

Comment: Yes. Create a vector3, then use a loop and increase x, y, or z by 1 before assigning to the position of the objects transform.

Comment: Could you provide example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inspector you will need to assign the `prefab` and set the `objectCount` and `spacing` values.  This will spawn the objects along the positive x axis starting at zero.  If you want to move the objects along a different axis, change the `x` in `position.x` to one of the other vector3 components (y, z).  To move along the axis in the opposite direction, invert the spacing value (eg. from 1 to -1).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int objectCount;
    public float spacing;

    void Start()
    {
        var position = new Vector3();

        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
            position.x += spacing;
        }
    }
}
```